# Can abstract class interface be templated

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Can an abstract class interface be templated
Can we use templates in the derived classes to populate the params?
How to define an interface params for these type of requirement

```
  class iconfigurator
    {
    public:
        iconfigurator();
        virtual ~iconfigurator();
        //EXpect the std::vector<class entry>& entries to be Template type.              
        virtual bool config(const std::string& configName,std::vector<class entry>& entries) const = 0;    
    };

    class derivedconfigurator : public iconfigurator
    {        
    public:
        derivedconfigurator();
        virtual ~derivedconfigurator();    
        virtual bool config(const std::string& configName,std::vector<class another_entry_type>& entries) const = 0;    
    }

    class derivedconfigurator2 : public iconfigurator
    {    
    public:
        derivedconfigurator2();
        virtual ~derivedconfigurator2();    
        virtual bool config(const std::string& configName,std::maps<key, value>& entries) const = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's `Types` in your example?

Comment: Where in this class do you want to use template parameters? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: If you are asking whether you can do `template <typename Types> class iconfigurator {...};`, then yes you can - but be aware that `iconfigurator<SomeType>` and `iconfigurator<SomeOtherType>` are distinct unrelated classes; you won't be able to have, say, `std::vector<iconfigurator*>` and treat them uniformly and polymorphically. If you are asking whether you can do `template <typename Types> virtual bool config(...);` then no, you cannot. There ain't no such thing as a virtual function template.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sounds like an answer!

Comment: Can you provide an example derived class?

Comment: @ L.F I have added derived classes

Answer (score 0):

Templates are just a shortcut for writing N functions or classes.

```
template <typename T> class MyClass {}
MyClass<int> mc1 {};
MyClass<int> mc2 {};
```

The compiler will generate the code for 2 different classes: `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<double>`. You could have written them yourself, it would have been exactly the same! So, there is actually no difference between a *normal* class and a class generated from a template. So, to the question *Can an abstract class interface be templated*, the answer is yes. Note though that you will have 1 abstract interface per type, as explained above (just think as if you had written the two definitions of `MyClass`). And of course, you can use templates in your derived classes as well.

What you cannot do is use a templated virtual function.  Why? Templates generate code at compile-time. Virtual functions are about figuring out which function to call at runtime. So, it is impossible for the compiler to know which code to generate, as the function to call is determined at runtime.

An example of a templated abstract interface:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    // YOU CAN DO THIS
    virtual void test() const = 0;

    // BUT YOU CANNOT DO THIS
    /*template <typename D>
    virtual void fct();*/ 

};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    void test() const override {}
};

int main()
{
    Base<int>* b = new Derived<int>();
    b->test();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```